# python regex to replace all windows newlines with spaces

Tags: python, regex

I did this:

```
from urllib import urlopen
import nltk
url = http://myurl.com
html = urlopen(url).read()
cleanhtml = nltk.clean_html(html)
```

I now have a long string in python which is full of text interrupted periodically by windows newlines `/r/n`, and I simply want to remove all of the occurrences of /r/n from the string using a regular expression. First I want to replace it with a space. As such, I did this:

```
import re
textspaced = re.sub("'\r\n'", r"' '", cleanhtml)
```

...it didn't work. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just a small syntax error:

```
htmlspaced = re.sub(r"\r\n", " ", html)
```

should work.

Comment: This makes assumptions about the order of the `\r\n` characters. Some html might contain `\n\r` or even `\n` only as newlines. If you want it to work regardless of the character order, you need to put the regex in square brackets: `re.sub(r"[\r\n]+", " ", html)`. Otherwise the regex in above answer is just as good as a normal string replace and not really using the additional functionality of regex.

Answer (score 35):

There's no need to use regular expressions, just

```
htmlspaced = html.replace('\r\n', ' ')
```

If you need to also match UNIX and oldMac newlines, use regular expressions:

```
import re
htmlspaces = re.sub(r'\r\n|\r|\n', ' ', html)
```

Comment: Duh. Of course :) Much better than using a regex in this case.

Comment: This makes assumptions about the order of the `\r\n` characters. Some html might contain `\n\r` or even `\n` only as newlines.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas Good point, amended the answer.